# Routing in ReactJS with props

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I have one main component where I have all state. 
And here I passed this states to two different components.
The problem is - I need to open this two components in two different links (`<TimeTracker />`, `<TimeCalendar />`).

Render them separately.

How can I made it with React-router? Is it possible?

Bellow is my code for main component

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.initStorage();
    this.state = {
      startTime: this.getStoreItem('startTime') || 0,
      currentTask: this.getStoreItem('currentTask') || '',
      results: this.getStoreItem('results') || [],
      calendarResults: this.getStoreItem('calendarResults') || []
    };
  }

  /**
   create an object in localStorage for timer data if it is not present
   */
  initStorage () {
    let data = localStorage.getItem('timeData');
    if (!data) {
      localStorage.setItem('timeData', JSON.stringify({}));
    }
  }

  /**
   * get item value from storage
   * @param key - item name
   */
  getStoreItem = (key) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('timeData'));
    return data[key];
  }

  /**
   * change item value in storage
   * * @param key - item name
   * @param value - new value for item
   */
  setStoreItem = (key, value) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('timeData'));
    data[key] = value;
    localStorage.setItem('timeData', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.setState({
      [key]: value
    });
  }

  render () {
    const { startTime, currentTask, results, calendarResults } = this.state;
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <TimeTracker
            results={results}
            setStoreItem={this.setStoreItem}
            startTime={startTime}
            currentTask={currentTask} />
          <TimeCalendar calendarResults={calendarResults} />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I am new in Routing and did not find some similar examples.

Please help to understand how to do it.
I can make routing for them, but if component do not have props.
But in my example I'm bewildered

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried react-router's `<Switch />`?

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure how it should looks in my example.
can I use it in render? what my main component should return in render and how to pass props in `<Roure>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extract from my reactjs code that should help you out :

Router.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
// route components
import  { HomePage }  from '../Pages/HomePage.jsx';
import  { LoginPage }  from '../Pages/LoginPage.jsx';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

In this file, you start off by defining the components that will be rendered following the url adress you will visit on your page. Here is one of these two components:

HomePage.jsx :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Menu, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { AppBarEX } from '../components/Appbar.jsx'

export class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBarEX />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

HomePage is defined as the landing page in React Router thanks to the "/" path. So when you land on the website you will automatically be directed to the HomePage. In the `<AppBarEX/>` I use this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
<Link to = "/login">
```

The  element allows you to define when and how you want to link to other pages, this is probably what you were looking for. In this situation the Link will send you to the login page. To place elements inside your link, you can wrap them within the Link: `<Link> your element </Link>`

Finally, the element you want to render in your main.jsx goes as follows :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from './Router.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('main_body'));
});
```

This will allow you to render the renderRoutes defined in the router.jsx. You can find out more here:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/02-rendering-a-route

Hope this helped you out! 
D.